# How to flip two words in a string, Java

Tags: java, string, split, swap, flip

So say I have a string called x that = "Hello world". I want to somehow make it so that it will flip those two words and instead display "world Hello". I am not very good with loops or arrays and obviously am a beginner. Could I accomplish this somehow by splitting my string? If so, how? If not, how could I do this? Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

1) split string into `String` array on space.

```
String myArray[] = x.split(" ");
```

2) Create new string with words in reverse order from array.

```
String newString = myArray[1] + " " + myArray[0];
```

Bonus points for using a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenation.

Comment: Use StringBuilder for two words? Java will do that all by itself. Premature optimalization?

Comment: @owlstead - to expand; while the above doesn't warrant using `StringBuilder`, it's good to know about it and the pitfalls of using string concatenation in java. Given the obvious beginner level of the OP it would be a good thing for him to learn early before it bites him ;)

Comment: @BrianRoach - If you are going to teach a lesson, it should be a *correct* lesson.  In *most cases*, it is *bad practice* to use `StringBuilder` instead of `+`.

Comment: @StephenC - AFAIK the compiler does this for you where it can, and Josh Bloch was pretty clear on it in his book. What's changed? I'm happy to repent :)

Comment: @BrianRoach Used a stringbuilder for this: `System.out.println(reverseWords("Owlstead is 01 very \"strange bïrd\"!"));` to get `!"bïrd strange" very 01 is owlsteaD`

Comment: @BrianRoach - I am fully aware that the *compiler* uses a StringBuilder in this context.  Your sentence *"Bonus points for using a StringBuilder instead of concatenation."* says that the *programmer* should use StringBuilder in this context.  (We don't award points to the compiler ...)  I'm saying that is an *incorrect* lesson.  (If you don't understand why it is incorrect for the programmer to use StringBuilder, tell me, and I'll explain.)

Comment: @BrianRoach - The reason I'm beating up on you for this is that I often see code where someone has made the mistake of rewriting a simple concatenation expression using StringBuilder ... because someone else said it was the right thing to do.  It is NOT.

Answer (score 1):

```
String abc = "Hello world";
String cba = abc.replace( "Hello world", "world Hello" );

abc = "This is a longer string. Hello world. My String";
cba = abc.replace( "Hello world", "world Hello" );
```

If you want, you can explode your string as well:

```
String[] pieces = abc.split(" ");
for( int i=0; i<pieces.length-1; ++i )
    if( pieces[i]=="Hello" && pieces[i+1]=="world" ) swap(pieces[i], pieces[i+1]);
```

There are many other ways you can do it too. Be careful for capitalization. You can use .toUpperCase() in your if statements and then make your matching conditionals uppercase, but leave the results with their original capitalization, etc.

Comment: Somehow, I don't think Lanuk was looking for an answer that just replaces the two words with another string.

Comment: hello world is just an e.g. the example is not usable for other strings

Comment: I assume you saw the rest of my post with the explode statement @ owlstead?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseWords {
    public String reverseWords(String phrase) {
        List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(phrase.split("[ ]"));
        Collections.reverse(wordList);

        StringBuilder sbReverseString = new StringBuilder();
        for(String word: wordList) {
            sbReverseString.append(word + " ");
        }

        return sbReverseString.substring(0, sbReverseString.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

The above solution was coded by me, for Google Code Jam and is also blogged here: [Reverse Words - GCJ 2010](http://google-tale.blogspot.com/2010/03/reverse-words-gcj-2010-africa.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just use this method, call it and pass the string that you want to split out

```
static String reverseWords(String str) {

    // Specifying the pattern to be searched
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");

    // splitting String str with a pattern
    // (i.e )splitting the string whenever their
    //  is whitespace and store in temp array.
    String[] temp = pattern.split(str);
    String result = "";

    // Iterate over the temp array and store
    // the string in reverse order.
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (i == temp.length - 1) {
            result = temp[i] + result;
        } else {
            result = " " + temp[i] + result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact requirements, you may want to split on other forms of whitespace (tabs, multiple spaces, etc.):

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)(\\s+)(\\S+)");
public String flipWords(String in)
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    if (m.matches()) {
        // reverse the groups we found
        return m.group(3) + m.group(2) + m.group(1);
    } else {
        return in;
    }
}
```

If you want to get more complex see the docs for Pattern http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something as follows:

```
String input = "how is this";
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
Collections.reverse(words);
String result = "";
for(String word : words) {
    if(!result.isEmpty()) {
        result += " ";
    }
    result += word;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
this is how
```

Answer (score 0):

Too much?

```
private static final Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("^(\\p{L}+)");
private static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("^(\\p{N}+)");
private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile("^(\\p{Z}+)");

public static String reverseWords(final String text) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length());

    final Matcher wordMatcher = WORD.matcher(text);
    final Matcher numberMatcher = NUMBER.matcher(text);
    final Matcher spaceMatcher = SPACE.matcher(text);

    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < text.length()) {

        wordMatcher.region(offset, text.length());
        numberMatcher.region(offset, text.length());
        spaceMatcher.region(offset, text.length());

        if (wordMatcher.find()) {
            final String word = wordMatcher.group();
            sb.insert(0, reverseCamelCase(word));
            offset = wordMatcher.end();
        } else if (numberMatcher.find()) {
            sb.insert(0, numberMatcher.group());
            offset = numberMatcher.end();
        } else if (spaceMatcher.find()) {
            sb.insert(0, spaceMatcher.group(0));
            offset = spaceMatcher.end();
        } else {
            sb.insert(0, text.charAt(offset++));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

private static final Pattern CASE_REVERSAL = Pattern
        .compile("(\\p{Lu})(\\p{Ll}*)(\\p{Ll})$");

private static String reverseCamelCase(final String word) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word.length());
    final Matcher caseReversalMatcher = CASE_REVERSAL.matcher(word);
    int wordEndOffset = word.length();
    while (wordEndOffset > 0 && caseReversalMatcher.find()) {
        sb.insert(0, caseReversalMatcher.group(3).toUpperCase());
        sb.insert(0, caseReversalMatcher.group(2));
        sb.insert(0, caseReversalMatcher.group(1).toLowerCase());
        wordEndOffset = caseReversalMatcher.start();
        caseReversalMatcher.region(0, wordEndOffset);
    }
    sb.insert(0, word.substring(0, wordEndOffset));
    return sb.toString();
}
```